# How to create user in Samba server using jcif library?

Tags: java, rpc, samba, jcifs, ms-samr

I start Samba server using following docker-compose:

```
services:
  samba:
    image: instantlinux/samba-dc:latest
    container_name: samba-dc
    cap_add:
      - CAP_SYS_ADMIN
    hostname: my.company
    environment:
      DOMAIN_ACTION: provision
      REALM: my.company
    volumes:
      - etc:/etc/samba
      - lib:/var/lib/samba
    ports:
      - "53:53"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "88:88"
      - "88:88/udp"
      - "389:389"
      - "139:139"
      - "446:445"
    secrets:
      - samba-admin-password
```

I want to create minimal reproducible example on java which allow to create user using SAMR protocol.

I've found library https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs

And there are some files/classes with names related to samr in the package [jcifs.dcerpc.msrpc](https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs/tree/master/src/main/java/jcifs/dcerpc/msrpc):

- MsrpcSamrCloseHandle.java
- MsrpcSamrConnect2.java
- MsrpcSamrConnect4.java
- MsrpcSamrOpenAlias.java
- MsrpcSamrOpenDomain.java
- SamrAliasHandle.java
- SamrDomainHandle.java
- SamrPolicyHandle.java
- samr.java

But I can't find any example of usage of those classes.

could you please help me with user creation implementaion ?

Comment: You'd probably be seeking one or more of SamrCreateGroupInDomain, SamrCreateAliasInDomain, SamrCreateUser2InDomain, SamrCreateUserInDomain in the source of that library. If none is present, it's likely not supported

Comment: I can't find any of them. But what purpose of those samr classes ?

Comment: They're not classes. They are SAMRx methods to create users (afaics)

Comment: @g00se I tried to use full text search and no results. For example https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acodelibs%2Fjcifs%20SamrCreateUserInDomain&type=code

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's not supported. You'd probably be best to ask the authors

Comment: @g00se do you know the way to access them ?

Comment: I can't even create issue on their github page https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs

Comment: I know .. nothing